# As my program (C#, NAudio) is playing an audio file, if it encounters 1 min of silence, I want to skip it

Tags: c#, naudio

My app plays audio files. As the it plays, I want to examine what's going to play for the next minute to see if it will all be silence; If so, I want to skip over the silence.

I'm trying to find a way to look at the stream before it's handed to WaveOutEvent.  I'm chaining AudioFileReader, SampleChannel, and OffsetSampleProvider.  I haven't found a method that would allow me to simply "peek" at upcoming data. I have looked at Mark Heath's PluralSight courses and the NAudio source code.

//This code is based on examples for Mark Health's NAudo Course on PluralSight.

...

```
    private string fileName;
    private IWavePlayer waveOut;
    ISampleProvider sampleProvider;

    private ISampleProvider CreateInputStream(string fileName)
    {
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(fileName);
        var sampleChannel = new SampleChannel(audioFileReader, true);
        var offsetSampleProvider = new OffsetSampleProvider(sampleChannel);
        return offsetSampleProvider;
    }

    private void Play()
    {
        ...

        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Paused)
            {
                waveOut.Play();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) GetFileName();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) return;

        try
        {
            CreateWaveOut();
        }
        catch (Exception driverCreateException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", driverCreateException.Message));
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            sampleProvider = CreateInputStream(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception createException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", createException.Message), "Error Loading File");
            return;
        }

       ...

        try
        {
            waveOut.Init(sampleProvider);
        }
        catch (Exception initException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}", initException.Message), "Error Initializing Output");
            return;
        }

        SetVolume(); 
        waveOut.Play();
    }

    private void CreateWaveOut()
    {
        CloseWaveOut();
        waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();
        waveOut.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
    }

    private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception != null) MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Playback Device Error");
        if (audioFileReader != null) audioFileReader.Position = 0;
    }

    private AudioFileReader audioFileReader;

    private void CloseWaveOut()
    {
        if (waveOut != null) waveOut.Stop();

        if (audioFileReader != null)
        {
            audioFileReader.Dispose();
            audioFileReader = null;
        }

        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;
        }
    }

   ...

    private void playToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Play();
    }

   ...

    private void stopToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut != null) waveOut.Stop();
    }

    private void openToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFileName();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut != null && audioFileReader != null)
        {
            TimeSpan currentTime = (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped) ? TimeSpan.Zero : audioFileReader.CurrentTime;
            trackBar1.Value = Math.Min(trackBar1.Maximum, (int)(100 * currentTime.TotalSeconds / audioFileReader.TotalTime.TotalSeconds));
            currentTimeStripLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)currentTime.TotalMinutes, currentTime.Seconds);
        }
        else
        {
            trackBar1.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    private void pauseToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing) waveOut.Pause();
        }
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (waveOut != null)
        {
            audioFileReader.CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(audioFileReader.TotalTime.TotalSeconds * trackBar1.Value / 100.0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

When the user listens to the dictation, silence that's greater than 1 min with be skipped.

--- this is additional info regarding my question ---

I watched the section of your PluralSight regarding how to Implement an ISampleProvider.  Pretty straightforward, thank you!  Here's what I have. (See below.)  But don't know how to create the in memory buffer you talked about.  Do I use BufferedWaveProvider?

public class SkipSilenceSampleProvider : ISampleProvider
    {
        public WaveFormat WaveFormat
        {
            get { return sourceProvider.WaveFormat; }
        }

```
    private readonly ISampleProvider sourceProvider;

    public SkipSilenceSampleProvider(ISampleProvider sourceProvider)
    {
        this.sourceProvider = sourceProvider;
    }

    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // Extract samples for the next minute and determine if the whole range is silence.
        int readCount = sourceProvider.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        return readCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by implementing a custom `ISampleProvider` that wraps your `AudioFileReader`. In the `Read` method, you'd need to read ahead enough from the source `AudioFileReader` to determine if there is silence that needs to be skipped. So you'd need a memory buffer containing a minutes worth of audio. Then the `Read` method should return the next non-silent samples. `Read` should always return the number of samples asked for unless you have reached the end of the source file.

Comment: Hi, Mark, thanks for the response!  I have to admit, I have never created a wrapper (Facade) class before.  Will you point me in the right direction on training/tutorial on how to create a wrapper class?  Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have been looking for tutorials on creating a Facade on the internet and I am looking at your Plural Sight courses again.

Comment: I'm looking at OffsetSampleProvider and using it as a basis for deriving my skip silence sample provider.  What do you think?

Comment: The design pattern here is actually called the "decorator" pattern as it implements the same interface, and delegates calls through to another implementation of the same interface. The OffsetSampleProvider is an example of this pattern in action, so would be useful. It doesn't need to do look-ahead though, which your use case requires, so it will be a bit more complex

Comment: Thanks!  I will look at it!